# CsharpSqlite on WP7

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, wp7test

I'm trying to create a silly app on WP7 which use a SQLite db.
To do this, I use a well know open source library called CsharpSqlite ( [CsharpSqlite's site](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) ). I lunched Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.WP project i fixed some build errors and then, using as start project SQLiteClientTests.WinPhone, I ran it in debug mode and it worked also if some tests failed.

My problem is when I try to run it in release mode. During the Bild, I have 747 Error.
I don't know how to fix it and why in debug mode it works and it doesn't work in release mode.

I also read the [compiler options](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/wiki/CompilerOptions) but they were ok.

now, to start to work i'm using an old version of this library (you can find it [here](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/)) but it's out of date and maybe it have some bugs.

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem? I am having the same issue...

Comment: I used NuGet to get a usefull solution called C# for SQLite https://www.nuget.org/packages/wp7sqlite/0.1.1 it's not bad.
I hope that it works for u